# Calculate the sum of a series with a given accuracy

Tags: c++, algorithm

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    system("chcp 1251>nul");
    int i = 1;
    double n;
    cin >> n;
    double eps = 0.00001;
    double sum = 0;
    double lastElementofSequence = 1;
    do {
        sum += lastElementofSequence;
        lastElementofSequence *= pow(9,i)/pow(2*n+1,i);
        i++;
    } while (fabs(lastElementofSequence) > eps);
    cout << sum << endl;
    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSefv.png)

Here is the problem, and I can’t figure out how to solve it by finding the next term through the preliminary!, And not every time to enumerate both the numerator and denominator in full.Code from above, but something is feeling something is not good, I will be grateful for the review, and sorry for such a stupid question, because I just started to study, I want to understand how to calculate such amounts because simple examples are easier

Comment: The question is unclear for me. Are you asking for a code review?

Comment: The sum `sum((9/7)^i/(2n+3), i=1...infinity)` is a geometric progression that doesn't converge. Is there a typo, and should `n` be `i`?

Comment: Actually, even if i and n are the same variable, the sum still diverges.

Comment: @ThomasSablik
And whether I performed this task correctly, if not, then indicate the errors, and if possible, correct it

Comment: Stackoverflow is the wrong platform for code reviews. Please ask for code reviews on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @PaulHankin
Well, I dropped the condition, so probably still n must be and it is indefinite if I'm not mistaken, or I misunderstood you

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying, but it sounds like you missed something critical from the description of the question. Can you clarify exactly what you think your code does (or is supposed to do), and in what way it doesn't behave as you expect?

Comment: @PaulHankin
Well, he has to calculate the sum of this series in the picture, but for some reason I'm not sure that he is right, because he is going to infinity, or I somehow misunderstand the condition

Comment: For `n != -3/2` the result of the sum is infinity. I think `lastElementofSequence *= pow(9,i)/pow(2*n+1,i);` should be `lastElementofSequence = pow(9,i)/((2*n+1)*pow(7,i));` but it doesn't change the result.

Comment: @ThomasSablik  Sorry, but there is an addition to the condition, if the series is divergent, then you need to correctly complete the work with the appropriate message to the user, as I understand it is impossible to count, so maybe this series is divergent?

Comment: That's what @PaulHankin told you in the second comment.

Comment: @ThomasSablik
So how do I write this? Because I'm already confused, to be honest

Comment: Do you mean `std::cout << "This series is divergent\n";`?

Comment: @ThomasSablik
Well in a condition writes here so "To consider that the number can be divergent. Then it is necessary to finish work correctly with the corresponding message to the user.", Then it is necessary to write something or somehow to count something I do not know

Comment: What does _"to finish work correctly"_ mean? This series is always divergent (`n != 3/2`). You don't need a condition.

Comment: @ThomasSablik
Well, I need to pass this task, so what should be the code?

Comment: We can help you with your code. We can also help you with the math. But we can't help you with understanding your assignment. If you don't know what you have to do we can't tell you. You have to ask your teacher/tutor. What does _"finish the work correctly"_ mean? If your assignment is to print a message if the series is divergent print a message because the series is divergent. You don't need the loop and calculation.

Comment: @ThomasSablik          and it is possible one more question only on other task, but I cannot ask it separately

Comment: What is possible?

Comment: @ThomasSablik 
Here I am now in response to this reset another problem that I solved, and I would like you to see if I solved it correctly

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtwBk.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    system("chcp 1251>nul");
    int i = 1;
    double x;
    cin >> x;
    if (abs(x) >= 1) { cout << "The series is divergent"; }
    else {
    double eps = 0.000001;
    double sum = 0;
    double lastElementOfSequence=1;
    do {
        sum += lastElementOfSequence;
        lastElementOfSequence *= -1 * x * (2 * i + 3) / (2 * i);
         i++;
    } while (fabs(lastElementOfSequence) > eps);
    cout.precision(17);
    cout << "sum=" << sum << endl;
    }
    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

whether I solve this problem correctly

Comment: Please don't post a question as answer. Ask a new question.

Comment: @ThomasSablik
I can not ask for some reason, writes that the service no longer accepts questions from this account at the moment

Comment: That's probably because you're deleting your question or your question are downvoted. Wait for some days, don't delete too many of your questions and ask better questions to avoid downvotes. You should read: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68884/why-cant-i-ask-questions-on-stackoverflow